# Change verification text using nexmo api?

Tags: vonage

Is it possible to change the text which is sent to user when using verification api?

I'm talking about this:

```
$requestId = $nexmo->verify()->start([
    'number' => '...',
    'brand'  => '...',
]);
```

As I realize there is no way to do it (I checked rest api), or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have different Verify templates, however, you will first need to submit a request for the new template and the request will have to be reviewed/approved by the support team.

Please see the following documentation:
https://developer.nexmo.com/api/verify/templates

More importantly:
https://developer.nexmo.com/api/verify/templates#create-a-custom-template

Comment: I see, but how can I manage my templates eg see their statuses, and how many verification templates I have, and how can I specify which template I use when sending the verification code? 
Or I can use only one template?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only have one active template at the time, therefore you can only use one Verify template a time.

The reason for this is to safeguard Nexmos services and other customers from abuse. If you wish to have a complete custom solution for 2FA, feel free to explore the SMS API:
https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/overview

However, you'd have to build up the verification system from scratch.